# In my Google Action, how do I efficiently conclude play of one MP3 and "skip" to another MP3 using a single user utterance?

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

I have a one-scene Action that calls my webhook '*randomSpeech*' (mentioned below) upon invocation, which plays an MP3. I added a "skip" intent to skip to the next MP3. When I say "skip", the Action should transition (loop) back into the webhook '*randomSpeech*', and since there is a counter, *x*, the Action should begin playing the 2nd MP3 in the *switch* statement.

**However, I have to say the word "skip" twice in order for it to work.**

1. The 1st time I say "skip", the system intent, MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED automatically calls the '*mediaStatus*' handler and the text 'Media has finished.' is added to the conversation. Even though I've configured the "skip" intent to call the handler, *'randomSpeech'*, it doesn't appear to happen as no new Media is added to the conversation. It's almost like  '*randomSpeech*', is completely ignored!
2. The 2nd time I say "skip", the second MP3 finally begins playing.

### My main question is, how can I make it so the user only has to say "skip" one time?

```
let x = 1;

app.handle('randomSpeech', (conv) => {

  switch(x) {
    case(1):
      conv.add(new Media({
      mediaObjects: [
        {
          name: 'NEVER GIVE UP',
          description: 'some athlete',
          url: 'http://zetapad.com/speeches/nevergiveup.mp3',
          image: {
            large: {
              url: 'https://www.keepinspiring.me/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/motivation-gets-you-started-jim-ryun-quote-min.jpg'
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      mediaType: 'AUDIO',
      optionalMediaControls: ['PAUSED', 'STOPPED'],
      startOffset: '5s'   
      }));
    x++;
    break;

    case(2):
      conv.add(new Media({
        mediaObjects: [
          {
            name: 'SPEECHLESS',
            description: 'Denzel Washington (feat Will Smith)',
            url: 'http://zetapad.com/speeches/denzel.mp3',
            image: {
              large: {
              url: 'https://www.keepinspiring.me/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/motivational-quotes-2-min.jpg'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        mediaType: 'AUDIO',
        optionalMediaControls: ['PAUSED', 'STOPPED']
      }));   
    break;
  }
});


app.handle('media_status', (conv) => {
  const mediaStatus = conv.intent.params.MEDIA_STATUS.resolved;
  switch(mediaStatus) {
    case 'FINISHED':
      conv.add('Media has finished.');
      break;
    case 'FAILED':
      conv.add('Media has failed.');
      break;
    case 'PAUSED' || 'STOPPED':
      if (conv.request.context) {
        // Persist the media progress value
        const progress = conv.request.context.media.progress;
      }
      conv.add(new Media({
        mediaType: 'MEDIA_STATUS_ACK'
        }));
      break;
    default:
      conv.add('Unknown media status received.');
  }
});
```

**Images from the only scene, "Motivation":**

[Scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le8CC.png)

[On enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69TNE.png)

[Intent handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQviZ.png)

**Further notes:**

- *MEDIA_STATUS_PAUSED* / *MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED* / *MEDIA_STATUS_STOPPED* all only call the '*media_status*' wehbook

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you update your question to include screen shots (or the YAML) from the Scene where this is taking place, as well as the Intents that are available in it?

Comment: Also, while your "side question" is a good one, it is best asked as a separate StackOverflow question. SO is best for one issue per question, and there is no penalty for asking multiple questions.

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for the advice. Added images and removed the "side Q."

Answer (score 0):

The issue at the heart of your question is that "skip" is a built-in Media Player command (although this is not clearly [documented](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media#behavior)), so when the user says "skip", the player treats this as the audio being [completed](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media#receiving_media_status), so it sends the `MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED` Intent, just as it the user listened to it all the way through.

The good news is - you actually want to handle both these cases the same way! So if the user skips to the next audio, or finishes the first and it should advance to the next audio - you want to play the next audio.

In your code, "playing the next audio" is all done as part of your switch statement. So you should probably put that into a regular JavaScript function by itself. You can then call that function from the different handlers that you have setup.

It might look something like this (without some of the code details):

```js
function nextAudio( conv ){
  // Code goes here to figure out the next audio to play and send it back
}

app.handle('randomSpeech', (conv) => {
  nextAudio( conv );
}

app.handle('media_status', (conv) => {
  const mediaStatus = conv.intent.params.MEDIA_STATUS.resolved;
  switch(mediaStatus) {
    case 'FINISHED':
      nextAudio( conv );
      break;
    // Other media status cases can go here
  }
});
```

Comment: This helps a lot. I have changed my code to mirror yours and it works for the most part. However, the built-in Media Player commands ("skip", "next") still don't play new audio. Even though `MEDIA_STATUS_FINISHED` now calls `nextAudio(conv)`. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Can you update your question to show your code as it is now? Have you confirmed that FINISHED is being called and that it is sending the media response? Can you provide screen shots from the simulator to illustrate what is happening?